# ServiceStack in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, servicestack, xamarin.forms

I'm having a werid issue with the recent updates. I'm Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and XF 2.3

I'm using Service Stack, and everything works cool but here's when the story goes werid.

I have a REST API with service stack, and the app is the client, but when I request a method, no matter if its using POST or GET the API response is correct but when it enters the app it goes to empty with a custom property type. I know it is correct because logs on the API says so and I know it reaches the app using WireShark.

If I run the same code (client methods) in a windows forms it works as spected but running it on Xamarin.Forms it does not.

the issue happens with a custom type I created but when I use the generic type

```
public class DataProperty
{
    protected string base64Value;

    public DataProperty();

    public string Value { get; }

    public byte[] Get();
    public DataProperty Set(byte[] data);

    public static implicit operator DataProperty(byte[] data);
    public static implicit operator byte[] (DataProperty PropertyValue);
}

public class DataProperty<T> : DataProperty
{
    public DataProperty();

    public DataProperty<T> Set(byte[] data);

    public static implicit operator DataProperty<T>(byte[] data);
    public static implicit operator byte[] (DataProperty<T> PropertyValue);
}
```

Service stack json returns:

```
[0:] {
  "Token": {
    "Value": "WFE1Au5DoIb0sEttlD3h08Xg+E+KwrZ5tFusJqP1TsSY6D6PACjcBAiub+ydX84Wa95Gu318ziDXssUnwe0fWE0L/0A6h5IcLEYk8xGxKdW3ooehjrOR/7KwEypZRcmVI6oKX75id21npQDJZP8Y4U18gBeJuuKjpckeL8b54U8="
  },
  "Id": {
    "Value": ""
  },
  "AId": {
    "Value": ""
  },
  "Iden": {
    "Value": ""
  },
  "ACID": 1522,
  "ResponseStatus": null
}

//SessionToken is a DataProperty
//Id is DataProperty<long>
//AId is DataProperty<double>
//Iden is DataProperty<string>
//ACID is long
//ResponseStatus is a service stack property not filled.
```

As I said, if I run exactly the same code on a PCL+Windows Forms(or even console) app it works correctly but running it on PCL+Xamarin.Forms it doesn't (using emulator or phisical phone)
Tried XF 2.1,2.2, 2.3.

[EDIT]
The client implementation method is an `async Task<bool>` and its like the following:

```
        MyMethodRequest request = new MyMethodRequest();
        using (JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(serviceURL))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await client.PostAsync(request);

                Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error:[" + e.Message + "]");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I'm using 
Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 
Xamarin 4.1.1.3 (34a92cd)
Xamarin.Android 6.1.1.1 (7db2aac)
Xamarion.iOS 9.8.1.4 (3cf8aae)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm still not sure how it's being populated, using the `JsonServiceClient`? Or are you using one of the helper methods? Could you provide the code you're using the in your app where your object gets populated successfully in WinForms but not Xamarin Forms? Also, could you provide concrete version of the POCO you are using? Going by the `DataProperty` class it looks like you are handling serialisation/deserialisation yourself?

Comment: thanks for your reply @layoric, I edited the question for showing up the client. The problem appeared after I upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015, the backend is the same as before the client stopped working, enlighten me on how to tell you the POCO version. Thanks again! BTW we have a licence for our backend using service stack.